# Android FragmentTransaction backstack restrict size

Tags: android, transactions, back-stack

Is it possible to programmaticly restrict the number(depth) of transaction back-stack?
I implemented "back" by adding fragmenttransactions to back-stack, but I do not want to have unlimited amount of them on the back stack. For example, to ignore the oldest ones.

This is the code for adding transactions to back-stack:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fragment f ....
fragmentTransaction.replace(id, f).addToBackStack(null);
```

tx